# Delete Single and Multiple entries in one View, PHP, MYSQL, HTML

Tags: php, forms, content-management-system, admin

How do I achieve the following?

I have a list of entries. [image: current implementation]

I want to be able to delete a single entry via the right "x"

But also I would like to be able to select multiple entries via the checkboxes on the left. After that, obviously clicking the "delete selected entries" at the bottom.

At the moment, all of this is in one form. Everything is links at the moment, not really what I want at all because it doesnt work.

Can anyone help me with a strategy or implementation that would enable me to get this working?

Heres the html code at the moment, I create it dynamically with some PHP, request if you want to see: :)

```
<form class="learnfest_form" method="post" action="">
    <h2>Delete a Learnfest Entry <small>Select an entry to delete</small></h2>
    <hr>
            <ul class="list-group checked-list-box">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="c1e42a9f9cfbdad684fa5a107a9967cef96a8a6e">&nbsp; L01<a class="pull-right" href="c1e42a9f9cfbdad684fa5a107a9967cef96a8a6e" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="0c0203b6b6d5105a3e72deac0b61be61236b1ff7">&nbsp; L02<a class="pull-right" href="0c0203b6b6d5105a3e72deac0b61be61236b1ff7" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="99a5cbf3ff728b5d6f3f524d301edc6a5d38feb9">&nbsp; L03<a class="pull-right" href="99a5cbf3ff728b5d6f3f524d301edc6a5d38feb9" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" value="31729ebd6fa5fcb0f17cdc1e3e5fe3c861149782">&nbsp; L04<a class="pull-right" href="31729ebd6fa5fcb0f17cdc1e3e5fe3c861149782" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Delete Selected Entries <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: at least you should show us that you tried something. have a look at `jquery $.ajax`

Comment: i've tried to find another way of doing it if you know what i mean. Normally I would use a hidden field so that I could get the id using $_GET. So for e.g. mywebsite.com?action=delete.particular.item&id=abc. And for the checkboxes I just submit the form and get the array of selected items. Is this the easiest solution?

Comment: there is no another option, like you said or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on **Delete Selected Entries** retrieve all `.list-group-item checkbox:checked` elements and make an AJAX request to your php page to delete all of them. Your request will be something like this:

```
{
  elementstodelete: [
    'c1e42a9f9cfbdad684fa5a107a9967cef96a8a6e',
    '0c0203b6b6d5105a3e72deac0b61be61236b1ff7'
  ]
}
```

On server side you use `json_decode()` to read all the elements and you'll make the magic query to delete them.

Comment: so you would do it via ajax, why not through $_GET?

Comment: I only associate ajax with api's, in my opinion it takes to long for such simple tasks.

Comment: If you want to make something usable and fast, I think it should be better to do this kind of requests using AJAX. Browsers shouldn't reload all the content of the page but simply send a request, receive a response and remove from the view what you deleted.